# How to create an AES-256 hex string using crypto.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I want to encode json into AES-256 and then make it into hex String.

However, the result is still empty. How can I solve this problem?

- env: node.js

```js
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

const STORE_KEY = "12345678912345678912345678912345"

EncryptHex(JSON.stringify(params), "AES");

const EncryptHex = (string, chip) => {
  let result = "";
  try {
    if (chip === "AES") {
      result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, STORE_KEY).toString(
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex
      );
        console.log("@@@@@@");
        console.log(result); // this is empty
        console.log("@@@@@@");
    } else {
      result = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(string, STORE_KEY).toString(
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex
      );
    }
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

and How can I proceed to decryption later?

Comment: Is `STORE_KEY` a string or a `WordArray`?

Comment: @Topaco STORE_KEY is int String

Comment: If the key is a string, then it's interpreted as a password, a random salt is generated, and from the password and salt a key and IV are derived using an OpenSSL function. The ciphertext contains a prefix, salt and ciphertext, is Base64 encoded and can be displayed with `result.toString()`. As long as you decrypt with CryptoJS this is no problem. But cross-platform (e.g. Java) it is, because this mechanism usually has to be implemented by yourself. Is that what you want or do you want to specify key and IV directly?

Comment: @Topaco I need to convert json value to string and encode it using AES-256 and then convert it to Hex string.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Should the key be derived as described or should it be entered directly? The further processing and also the later decryption depends on it.

Comment: @Topaco  
The value of the key must be entered directly

Comment: OK, then you have to pass the key as `WordArray`. For this it must be parsed with an [encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders). You also need an IV which must also be passed as `WordArray`, see e.g. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv).

Comment: @Topaco 
If all the key values ​​are numbers, which parsing should I use?

Comment: AES requires a key that is 128, 192 or 256 bits in size. The encoder depends on the encoding (e.g. Utf8 for a Utf8 encoding), I can't say more without an example.

Comment: Note also, that the IV (16 bytes for AES) isn't secret and is usually placed before the ciphertext, the whole thing is Base64 encoded and sent to the recipient. The recipient separates IV and ciphertext and can decrypt with this information.

Comment: @Topaco I want to make it a hex string, not base64.

Comment: `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` returns a `CipherParams` object, which among other things encapsulates the ciphertext, i.e. `result.ciphertext.toString()` returns the ciphertext hex encoded.

Comment: @Topaco Currently, the value is converted to base64 by default. But I want it to be returned as hex string, not base64 value.

Comment: Shouldn't be. Please edit your question and post your most recent code (containing the modifications).

Comment: @Topaco  I was wrong. `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, STORE_KEY).toString(
 CryptoJS.enc.Hex);` is not working but `result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, { iv: key });
      result = result.ciphertext.toString();` is working Thanks

Comment: You' re welcome. Note that iv = key is insecure, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/problems-with-using-aes-key-as-iv-in-cbc-mode). Better is a new, random IV for each encryption, which is passed to the recipient as described above.

Comment: @Topaco Ah~ I see, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of @Topaco.

```js
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(STORE_KEY);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(STORE_IV);
result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, { iv: key });       
result = result.ciphertext.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const STORE_KEY = ''// your key
function aes256 (string) {
    let result = ''
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', STORE_KEY)
    result = decipher.update(string, 'hex', 'utf8')
    result += decipher.final('utf8')
    return result
}
aes256('lalala')
```

and SHA256:

```
let string = '' // your data
let result = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', STORE_KEY).update(string).digest('hex')
```

thanks

Comment: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated

Comment: try createDecipheriv ? crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', STORE_KEY, STORE_IV) ?

Comment: STORE_IV  can be null。 refer to link:http://nodejs.cn/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options.